# Why is the "Top Stories" Blurry in internet explorer? (From google)

Tags: windows, firefox, internet-explorer, images, google-search

This is a strange question, but why is the news top stories blurry on internet explorer? I took two screenshots to compare Internet explorer and Firefox (same search, news)

**Click on the images to see higher resolution, SuperUser degrades their quality.**

*Firefox:[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cf2uS.jpg]*

*Internet Explorer:[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTdqo.jpg]*

**As you can see, everything is blurry in internet explorer, the letters and pictures.**

**However, Firefox with the same search results is not blurry.**

Why is it blurry in internet explorer and not Firefox? Is this Google's fault or internet explorer, and if so is there a way to fix it? Thanks

Comment: I've tried, but I don't get the same results. It may be that 'TrueType' is off. They are also using custom fonts, which may cause an issue if you are running and older browser. What version of IE?

Comment: @mt025 Internet explorer 11, and what is truetype? Can you elaborate, and please take a screenshot of your screen.

Comment: On the text, it looks like IE is using ClearType or similar (subpixel rendering to smooth the edges), and FF is not.  The images look pretty similar to me.  If there's a difference, it's pretty subtle.

Comment: Follow these instructions to calibrate ClearType and then ensure you enable ClearType for HTML in Internet Explorer options. http://www.thewindowsclub.com/web-fonts-appear-blurry-internet-explorer

Comment: @misha256 I setup cleartype, not much of a difference and the news section still looks like that. And, I cannot find where to enable/disable Cleartype in the internet explorer settings, the tutorial doesn't have a screenshot of it either, unless its is the "Enable alternative codecs in HTML5" option

Comment: @fixer1234 did you click the images and view them side by side? It is very noticeable in the webpage with the sharp text to compare to. I can take another screenshot if you'd like. (The previews here on the question page are very degraded and both look blurry, but that is not the case.)

Comment: I clicked on the images and viewed them full size.  The effect on the text was obvious.  I thought I saw some subtle differences on the pictures but couldn't tell what I was looking at.  BTW, you can fine-tune ClearType, but it will still be less sharp because that is its function.

Comment: @fixer1234 I did mess with ClearType, but turning it on and off has no effects on the "top stories" tiles. It almost seems to me that google is using a picture of the tile and maybe it isn't scaling properly. However, since it's text it shouldn't look bad, right? I don't know :|